# Abrasive cutoff saw cuts skew in the vertical

Tags: metal-cutting

I've been using an abrasive cutoff saw to cut square tubing. The square tubing is 2.5mm thick and about 3cm wide. The abrasive saw is not cutting straight vertically, is this a problem with the tool or perhaps the abrasive disk or am I using the tool incorrectly?

I've tried looking for articles related to cut off saws but I couldn't find any that mentioned problems with the cut being skew vertically.

Just to be clear, I'm not talking about the function that some saws have to make for example 45 degree mitred cuts. If I locked in the saw on 45 degrees or 10 degrees, that would not matter, it would still be skew in the vertical.

Here's the cut and the blade.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you pushing it, or letting it cut? That's a fairly normal thing if you push the saw faster than it wants to go, IME. OTOH, is the edge of the disk either square or uniformly (centered) rounded? it might need to be dressed. [edit] to add pictures showing the cut and the shape of the blade.

Comment: Probably the blade and can only replace with a new one.  Check that the pivot point of saw is tight and does not wobble.  Check the blade mount and base for any dirt/debris causing blade or piece of steel to be off  square.

Comment: I will try to get some pictures of the disk and the resulting cuts. I also think it's possible that I'm pushing too hard.

Comment: There are several factors that may be at play here.  One is the flexibility of the saw shaft and bearings.  When the blade is pushed into the workpiece, the force on the blade will tend to bend the shaft or flex the bearings and make the blade cut at an angle.  This problem can be alleviated to a degree by simply reducing the pressure on the blade -- let is ease its way through the workpiece rather than forcing it through.

Comment: Is this a brand-new saw with the included blade? Rule of thumb is that the first thing you do when you buy a power saw is replace the blade as the included one is the cheapest thing they can get. I recently bought a table saw and it just wanted to pull the wood away from the fence. Finally bought a new blade and that solved the problem.

Comment: Have you checked that the blade and base is true 90 degrees?  Is cut the same or different degrees of being off?  Does cut in straight line or curved?

Comment: A couple of thoughts from reading the comments: I think I might be pushing too hard. It's difficult to see if the blade is rounded but it might be a bit rounded. There are no debris, I checked. It is a new saw, still using the included blade. The blade and base is 90 degrees. It cuts in a straight line.

Comment: tape a dime/penny/nickel to the stage right next to the blade to tilt the bar back slightly, compensating for the angle introduced by the tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New saws are not always exactly a true 90 and you may have to adjust the saw even new to get a proper cut.

I also know with my 14” abrasive saw if I dog the cut or pull hard it tends to skew so I start the cut then back off allow the blade to come back up to speed and cut some more once the blade dogs down or slows I back off again always allowing time for the blade to come back to speed.

Abrasive blades are different than wood blades as there is no left and right tooth sets so it all comes down to how you cut.

I can make the most expensive blade cut exactly as you have and then with the same setup put the cheapest blade on and get a perfect cut, the only difference is in the method , backing off allowing the blade to come to speed and if I notice one side touching after coming back to speed moving up and down and burning that side off so it won’t push the blade and create a skewed cut, yes this takes longer and a series of up and down cycles but will produce a straighter cut.

As with all things the saw must be true to make a good cut first then technique will make the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Is the stock being held by a mechanical clamp or are you holding it by hand?  if the latter, the stock may be moving ever so slightly on you.  I have seen this a lot with a miter saw and it pulling the stock how it wants to.